# Creating a join site link for share site in alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to sent an email notification whenever a new site is created. I created the rule in site and made a java script to execute. Here is my javascript

```
var parent = space.getParent();
var siteShortName = space.getSiteShortName();
var siteGroup = "GROUP_EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS";
var mail = actions.create("mail");
mail.parameters.to_many = siteGroup;

mail.parameters.subject=" A new site called" +siteShortName +"is created";
mail.parameters.text="Login to share to join the site;

//execute action against a document
mail.execute(document);
```

But I am getting mail as `A new site callednullis created‏` in subject. It is not saying the name of the site.

How to add the site name?
How to add the link to join the site?
It is also sending four mails instead of one

Here is my rule:
[image]

Comment: Java script which you are using is placed where? I just want to get idea under which context you are executing this script because based on that  you way of accessing sitename differ

Comment: It is in `datadictionary/script`, now I am able to get the site name. But it is sending two emails

Comment: So, this is another issue I guess. One mail may be from your rule and another through out of box configuration

Comment: Any idea on how to stop the two mail

Comment: I found the issue is related to number of members in the group. If the the group email contributor has two members it will send two mails, three members then three and so on

Comment: In that case you can change script where it iterate through all users to whom you want to send mail and send them one by one rather then all group.

Comment: Do I need to add the email address of all one by one?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Javascript Site Services API](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/4.0_JavaScript_Services_API#Site) may help you.

Comment: I managed to send the email; but the problem is share is sending two email notification.

Comment: are you sure that your rule trigger is "created" only? Additional "updated"-event may be fired

Comment: @above Yes I selected only `When items are created or enter the folder`

Answer (score 0):

space.getParent() returns a ScriptNode & not a Site-Object.
just try the following:

```
var siteShortName = space.properties.name; // or space.properties.title if you'd like to get the displayName instead
```

Comment: Thanks I added that but the share is sending two email notifications on every site creation

Comment: as said before - are you sure that your rule trigger is "created" only? Additional "updated"-event may be fired

Comment: I added the image of my rule

Comment: well, this looks like a *bug*. use a Policy/Behaviour for st:site as a workaround

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What to do?

Comment: In alfresco forum it is written as - record the fact that an email has been sent and supress the subsequent emails.
- send your email post-commit (although there is then a danger that the email may fail) How to do that

Comment: I found the issue is related to number of members in the group. If the the group email contributor has two members it will send two mails, three members then three and so on